# how to bind angularjs controller data to bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, binding, popover

In my angularJs app, i am using bootstrap popover and having problem of binding controller data to content of popover.
below is my code.

```
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="rpt in obj.reports track by rpt.name">
                    {{rpt.name}}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                          data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover"
                          title="Driver reports" data-content="rpt.info" popover>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Please help me how to bind {{rpt.info}} to data-content of popover.

Answer (score 0):

So for making bootstrap work with angular, you could use one of these awesome modules.

[Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)
or
[Angular UI Boostrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

**Angular Strap's modal:** 
http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals 
**Angular UI's modal:** 
 https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score 0):

I would use UI Bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/top) since it is an Angular app.  Here's your code using UI Bootstrap:

```js
    var app = angular.module('popoverApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
      var vm = this;

      this.reports = [{
        name: 'Report 1',
        info: 'this is report 1'
      }, {
        name: 'Report 2',
        info: 'this is report 2'
      }, {
        name: 'Report 3',
        info: 'this is report 3'
      }];
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="popoverApp">

<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as obj">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="rpt in obj.reports track by rpt.name">
      {{rpt.name}}
      <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" uib-popover="{{rpt.info}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-title="Driver reports" popover-placement="right">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome.  Please mark this as the correct answer so that others will know that it has been answered.